# How to get specific attribute value?

Tags: jquery

I want to know how I can get the value of `data-id` from my div:

```
<div class="customer-row selected-row" data-id="83BA1B29-15B9-4B11-BA47-DEB453362426"><strong>Mario Rossi</strong></div>
```

I tried with:

```
$('#customer-row .selected-row').data('id');
```

but return undefined, why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('.customer-row .selected-row').data('id')`. You have got `#customer-row` there in the jquery statement which resolves to nothing.

Comment: One question.  Why are you using `<strong>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your selector is wrong, you selector tries to find an element with class `selected-row` inside the element with id `customer-row`, instead you should be selecting an element which has both the class, I hope you know that `#` is for ID and `.` is for class. So just do:

```
$('.customer-row.selected-row').data('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not correct. `customer-row` is `class` not `id` and also remove the space between `.customer-row` and `.selected-row`. Try like following.

```
$('.customer-row.selected-row').data('id');
```